# Prototype selection of elements

Tags: prototypejs

I am trying to update the text inside a div. But when I use the below types of selections I get null.

```
my.class = Class.create(
{

 initialize:function(container){

   this._popup = new Element("div",{"id":"tm-popup"});
   var innerEl = "<div class='content'><div></div></div>";

  this._popup.insert(innerEl);
  container.insert({bottom:this._popup});

 },

 show:function(){
  var tempText = "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.";

  console.log("div = ", this._popup.select('content') );
  console.log("div = ", $('#tm-popup').select('.content') );

  $('#tm-popup').select('.content').update( tempText );

 }


});
```

I have tried 3 ways to try and get the div to update its text but all 3 fail. 
I want to stay away from $$ as a selector as I have a huge DOM tree and don't want to run through everything with the $$

If I do a log on this._popup in the show method it does trace out the object so I know its there.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who might run into this issue here is an answer.

```
$(this._popup).down('.content').update(tempText);
```